# How to truncate database table using n98-magerun2?

Tags: magento2, database, magento2.2, sql, magerun

I am trying to truncate the database table using n98-magerun2 version 3.2.0 and having some difficulties.

I know there is a command with option to run an SQL query:

```
db:query Executes an SQL query on the database defined in env.php
```

I had a look at this blog entry, however, the result is a bit different: https://alanstorm.com/n98-magerun-database-commands/

Even simple SELECT is not working. When I run:

```
n98-magerun db:query "SELECT * FROM cms_page"
```

I get following error:

> [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]
>
> Too many arguments, expected arguments "command" "query".

Any help will be appricaited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to run it non-interactive, request for command prompt, then enter your query:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

# Get a shell
spawn n98-magerun db:query

# Wait for a prompt
expect "SQL Query:"

# Type something
send "SELECT * FROM cms_page\r"

#interact
```

or if you can try to use singles, not double quotes:

```
n98-magerun db:query 'SELECT * FROM cms_page'
```

or just enter command, then enter your query in prompt:

```
n98-magerun db:query
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just truncate the table via mysql cli directly?

```
mysql -u root -p'' magento -e 'truncate table `magento`.`table_to_truncate`'
```

Comment: That's what I did at the end, but I wanted to know if there is a way of doing it using the MageRun :P